# How to create PersistentArrayMap preventing evaluation?

Tags: replace, clojure, datomic

My question is quite simple but weird at the same time, I would like to create a PersistentArrayMap avoiding evaluation at the same time that I would like to get the value inside this. What is the best solution? I mean

Imagine that I have this def:

```
(def queen "catherine the great")
```

And would like to do something like this (single quote):

```
'{:queen queen}
```

for sure the output is 
`=> {:queen queen}`

But i expected do something like this
`=> {:queen "catherine the great"}`

I know that I can just do it

```
(array-map :queen queen)
```

But in my case I would like only evaluate some information cause my map is more complicated, like a datomic query:

```
'{:find  [(pull $ ?c [*])]
    :with  []
    :in    [$ ?queen-name]
    :where [
            [$ ?c :queen/name ?queen-name]
            ]
    :args [queen-name]}
```

for this case I would like only to evaluate queen-name.

My question is, there's a simple way to do it? Maybe using update?

something like this?

```
(assoc-in '{:find  [(pull $ ?c [*])]
          :with  []
          :in    [$ ?queen-name]
          :where [
                  [$ ?c :queen/name ?queen-name]
                  ]
          :args []} [:args] ["catherine the great"])
```

Answer (score 2):

For both examples, you can use [syntax-quote and unquote](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote):

```clj
user=> (def queen-name "catherine the great")
#'user/queen-name
user=> `{:queen ~queen-name}
{:queen "catherine the great"}
user> {:find  '[(pull $ ?c [*])]
    :with  '[]
    :in    '[$ ?queen-name]
    :where '[
            [$ ?c :queen/name ?queen-name]
            ]
    :args `[~queen-name]}
{:find [(pull $ ?c [*])],
 :with [],
 :in [$ ?queen-name],
 :where [[$ ?c :queen/name ?queen-name]],
 :args ["catherine the great"]}
```

Comment: yes it works for syntax-quote but not for single-quote, I use single-quote cause I need the expression in this case of datomic. Sorry about my question missing this information and thx for you fast response and help

Comment: @PauloVictor I haven't used Datomic, so I'm not sure how it works, but from a quick glance at the docs it looks like the query API accepts a map where the individual fields are quoted, as above. So, instead of quoting the entire map, you can quote the vector value associated with the key `:find`, for example.

Comment: @PauloVictor Why do you want to evaluate the `queen-name` field? You could also just quote the values that need to be quoted and leave the vector associated with `:args` unquoted, as in this example: https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/client/client-api.html#timeouts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in general, you can use [tupelo.quote](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.211/api/tupelo.quote).

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [tupelo.quote :as q]))

; problem:  free symbols a and b are fully-qualified using current ns
`[a b ~(+ 2 3)] => [demo.core/a
                    demo.core/b
                    5]

(q/tmpl-fn '[a b (insert (+ 2 3))])  =>  [a b 5]

(let [a 1 b 2]
  (q/tmpl [a b (insert (+ 2 3))]))  =>  [1 2 5]

(is= [1 [2 3 4] 5] (q/tmpl [1 (insert (t/thru 2 4)) 5]))
(is= [1  2 3 4  5] (q/tmpl [1 (splice (t/thru 2 4)) 5]))
```

For Datomic in particular, you can [use query inputs](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#multiple-inputs):

```
(def some-name "John Lennon") ; parameter

;; query
(d/q  '[:find ?release-name    ; query pattern (quoted)
        :in $ ?artist-name
        :where [?artist :artist/name ?artist-name]
               [?release :release/artists ?artist]
               [?release :release/name ?release-name]]

     db, some-name  ; inputs (not quoted)
)
```

with result

```
#{["Power to the People"] 
  ["Unfinished Music No. 2: Life With the Lions"] 
  ["Live Peace in Toronto 1969"] 
  ["Live Jam"]
  ...}
```